# Bibtex remove numbers on top, enable hanging indention, remove numbers beside citation

Tags: bibtex

Hello So I have three problems:

1) How can you remove the two numbers on top of the word reference?
2) How do you remove the number before the citation?
3) And how do you make the second line indent? (enable Hanging Indention)

Thanks a lot! :)
So here's the code:

hello.bib:

```
@ARTICLE {anderson,
author  = "Anderson, K. and A. Bows",
title   = "Philisophical Transactions of the Royal Society A",
journal = {``Beyond 'dangerous' climate change: emission scenarios for a  new world ''},
year    = {2011},
number  = {369:},
pages   = {20-33.}
}
@ARTICLE {arrow,
author  = "Arrow, K.J.,",
title   = "Journal of Political Economy",
journal = {``A Difficulty in the Concept of Social Welfare''},
year    = {(August, 1950)},
number  = {58(4)},
pages   = {328–346}
}
```

hello.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{anderson}
\cite{arrow}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{hello}
\end{document}
```

So this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! 1) These are your citations. Don't you want to cite those things? 2) These are the labels for the citations so that your reader can find the relevant entries in your list of references. If you remove them, how will the reader know which entry you are citing. (Of course, if you remove the citations as well, this won't be a problem, strictly speaking.) This is just how citations work. When you cite, you provide a label for the reader. When you list the source, you put the label so the source can be located by the reader using the label.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! haha but then this is my homework and I need to copy the exact same thing of a PDF file given to us using latex. and in that PDF file there are no numbers beside the reference, and we are required to use Bibtex :(

Comment: In the `arrow` entry, you should split the information for the `volume` and `number` fields (as well as interchange the `title` and `journal` fields).

Comment: You ought not be asking other people to do your homework for you!

Answer (score 2):

**I'm not sure, it is a good idea to make you your homework,  so I only show you how to get rid of the labels and the indention.**

But there are still errors in your `bib` file **I leave to you** to correct them **for real homework**.  Have a look to the error messages and warnings for the `bibtex` run!

With `\nocite` you get rid of the citation marks in the document.  With style `apalike` or `apa` the labels are gone and with `\bibhang` you can set the indention to zero or another value you want.  Package `filecontents` is used to have `bib` file and TeX code concatenated into only one file for the mwe.

The mwe:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE {anderson,
author  = "Anderson, K. and A. Bows",
title   = "Philisophical Transactions of the Royal Society A",
journal = {``Beyond 'dangerous' climate change: emission scenarios for a  new world ''},
year    = {2011},
number  = {369:},
pages   = {20--33.},
}
@ARTICLE {arrow,
author  = "Arrow, K.J.,",
title   = "Journal of Political Economy",
journal = {``A Difficulty in the Concept of Social Welfare''},
year    = {(August, 1950)},
number  = {58(4)},
pages   = {328-–346},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % test both: apa and apalike
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

But there are errors is the `bib` file! **Correct them! And please study my code.** See also the small changes I did in the `bib` file. **Think about why I did this.** Read the documentation for `bibtex`.  (Find the wrong comma in entry `arrow`!)

Comment: I realized what my mistake is now in bib file. Thanks a lot! :) You're of good help! I am just a beginner and I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: I think the OP did want hanging indentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed several errors in the bib file. Among them are (i) the contents of the `journal` and `title` fields are reversed in both entries, (ii) the contents of `volume` and `number` fields aren't kept track of separately, (iii) the values of `month` and `year` fields aren't split, and (iv) plain old typos (Philisophical -> Philosophical).

In addition, if you don't want to use a numeric citation call-out style, you need to specify a style (and, possibly, options to a citation management package such as `natbib`) that let you switch to an authoryear citation call-out style. E.g., you may want to look into using the `apalike` bibliography style.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytest.bib}
@ARTICLE {anderson,
author  = "Anderson, K. and A. Bows",
journal = "Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society~A",
title   = {Beyond `dangerous' climate change: emission scenarios for a  new world},
year    = {2011},
volume  = 369,
pages   = {20-33}
}
@ARTICLE {arrow,
author  = "Arrow, K. J.",
journal = "Journal of Political Economy",
title   = "A Difficulty in the Concept of Social Welfare",
year    = {1950},
month   = "August",
volume  = {58},
number  = 4,
pages   = {328--346}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document} 
\citet{arrow}, \citet{anderson}
\bibliography{mytest}
\end{document}
```